# Why does pie chart COMobject have axes?

Tags: c#, excel, reflection

I'm trying to check if each chartObject I'm iterating over has a certain property (axes), and if so apply gridlines. Something like this, assuming the code would work:

```
foreach (ChartObject chartObject in chartObjects)
{
    yAxis = chartObject.Chart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary)

    if ( yAxis != null)
    {
            yAxis.HasMajorGridlines = true; //Should enter for Line chart, not for Pie Chart
    }
}
```

My intuition tells me that during the iteration when the chartObject is a pie chart, yAxis should be null, because a pie chart has no axis. However, it seems like Axes is still a COMObject for the pie chart, and therefore is not null. That leads to it entering the if statement, trying to add gridlines and throwing a NullReferenceException.

Thanks,
Fredrik

Comment: Given it does have them, how will understanding _why_ it has them help you at all?

Comment: Have you considered checking the ChartType rather than looking at the Axes? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcharttype

Comment: Sorry if my motives are not clear. I'm trying to understand the way the ChartObject is built, and why a pie chart would have an axis object that returns anything else than null. Apparently the Axis is not null for a pie chart, and the code above therefore cannot solve my problem.  I will have to find another way to distinct the charts in which I can add major gridlines and the ones where I can not.

Comment: `I will have to find another way to distinct the charts in which I can add major gridlines and the ones where I can not.` Perhaps by `ChartType`?

Comment: Yes @mjwills. That works, however there are 100+ different charttypes in excel and I'd like to find a simple way to distinct if a chart has the possibility to add gridlines. Checking whether a chartobject has any axes is another way to go, however that would leave out a linechart without axes, even though it can in fact have gridlines although it has no axes present.